# Add Rows to a DataTable without losing the previous rows

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Dim  _tableBackLogs As System.Data.DataTable

Do While i - 2 > 0
_tableBackLogs = Global.DataAccess.GetDataTable("SELECT SubjectID,SubjectName,Grade FROM SubjectPI WHERE RegNo='" & CInt(HttpContext.Current.Session("userName")) & "' AND Status='Fail' AND Semester='" & i - 2 & "'")
i = i - 2
Loop
```

Doing this replaces the previous data in the `DataTable`. I want to retain the previous data i.e i want the new rows to be added to the DataTable w/o replacing the previous rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with following.

```
Dim _tableBackLogs As New System.Data.DataTable

Do While i - 2 > 0
    _tableBackLogs.Merge(Global.DataAccess.GetDataTable("SELECT SubjectID,SubjectName,Grade FROM SubjectPI WHERE RegNo='" & CInt(HttpContext.Current.Session("userName")) & "' AND Status='Fail' AND Semester='" & i - 2 & "'"))
    i = i - 2
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use Merge method

```
Dim  _tableBackLogs As System.Data.DataTable

Do While i - 2 > 0
_tableBackLogs.Merge(Global.DataAccess.GetDataTable("SELECT SubjectID,SubjectName,Grade FROM SubjectPI WHERE RegNo='" & CInt(HttpContext.Current.Session("userName")) & "' AND Status='Fail' AND Semester='" & i - 2 & "'"))
i = i - 2
Loop
```

Comment: `Variable _tableBackLogs is used before it has been assigned a Value`    **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**